# Check if value is a multiple of some integer value

Tags: delphi

How can i check if a value is a multiple of 6 or 7.

example

```
....
var
numbers
being
 if (numbers is a multiple of 6 or 7) then begin
    memo1.lines.add(inttostr(numbers));
    numbers := numbers+1;
 end;
```

Comment: *var numbers being*? You should take more care. Why do you expect us to care if you don't show that you do?

Comment: Agreed we need to clarify that you are talking strictly about integers.

Comment: Homework grade question, indeed.

Comment: yes integers, thus the 6 and 7....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check whether a number is exactly divisible by another, you use the [remainder operator](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_%28Delphi%29#Arithmetic_Operators), `mod`:

> The **mod** operator returns the remainder obtained by dividing its operands.

The condition you need to test is that the remainder, after division by the divisor, is 0.

As a concrete example, 12 is divisible by 6 because its remainder after division is 0. But 13 is not divisible by 6, the remainder after dividing 13 by 6 is 1.

So, you can use a function like this:

```
function IsExactlyDivisibleBy(Number: Integer; Divisor: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Assert(Divisor>0);
  Result := Number mod Divisor = 0;
end;
```

Comment: What is the benefit of `Assert` here?  Why is it preferable to have the function raise `EAssertionFailed` instead of `EZeroDivide` (which clearly explains the problem).

Comment: @J... I did not want to have to think about what Divisor < 0 means.

Comment: Afaik, `Divisor < 0` is fine and works just the same (in the sense of *'exactly divisible by'*, at least), which your function makes more clear about its purpose than `mod`.

Comment: @J... I think you are right. I just didn't want to deal with it!!

Answer (score 2):

Use modulus to determine if there is a remainder from a division by a number

```
(number mod 6 = 0) // if expression is true then it is a multiple
```

so for instance in the above example if number was 7 it would return 1

Comment: @GlenMorse - `%` is used in C

Comment: The Pascal (and Delphi) equality operator is "=" and not "==".

Comment: Yes, my apologies I am currently using c# and it's became a habit! I'll edit my answer accordingly.